# Java : Rounding a decimal value to HALF_EVEN

Tags: java, math, decimal, rounding, bigdecimal

I have been trying to write a java code to Round a value to the below requirement.

If x=63.88 => roundedValue= 64.00;

If x=63.50 => roundedValue= 64.00

If x=63.32 => roundedValue= 63.32

I tried with the different roundingModes like CEILING, DOWN, FLOOR, HALFDOWN.
I also tried Math.round();

But I'm unable to get the expected output.
My input is a string and output is a string.

Please find the code snippet I tried below

```
BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal(input);
value1=value1.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
//float rounded=Math.round(amount);

String finalValue=String.valueOf(value1);
```

I'm unable to get the desired output. Please let me know how to achieve this?

ps: should i consider using float or BigDecimal??

Comment: If x=63.32 => roundedValue= 63.32 ????

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik - Yes

Comment: Your specification makes no sense, as you're simply not rounding 63.32. We can't help without some sort of rule to apply.

Comment: Do you mean something like: if x rounds up, then round up, else do nothing?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(x%1 >= .5)
  { x = Math.round(x) }
else //do nothing
```

This seems like it would give you the desired output you are looking for. So if you really wanted to you could override or create your own method to call for the rounding

Comment: `>= .5` may return rather unfriendly results for certain values. I stongly suggest using Double.compareTo / Double.compare

Comment: @Vogel612 - unfriendly results like? can you please provide some examples?

Comment: comparing `(.7 - .2) >= .5` will return false, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30404771/1803692

Comment: I would not recommend working with double and float when trying to use decimal rounding. Use decimal numbers for decimal rounding and binary numbers for performance relevant things.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do with this, is providing your own `MathContext` to specify the behavior of the rounding you want to perform.

The closest you will get to your current requirements is either: using `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` or `RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY`

For that you will have to use `BigDecimal` anyways, since Double and Float do not expose rounding.

Answer (score 0):

As in your post, using `BigDecimal` is the way to go, if you want to use **decimal rounding**.

If you want to round up for numbers >= X.5 and avoid rounding for numbers < X.5 then you can use this code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Round {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(round("63.88"));
        System.out.println(round("63.50"));
        System.out.println(round("63.32"));
    }

    private static BigDecimal round(String input) {
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(input);

        BigDecimal rounded = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        if (rounded.compareTo(value) > 0)
            return rounded.setScale(2);

        return value;
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
64.00
64.00
63.32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Double d = 63.18;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");

    if(d % 1 >= 0.5) 
        System.out.println(df.format(Math.round(d)));
    else 
        System.out.println(d);
}
```